# Length of segment $PA$ in rectangle $ABCD$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In rectangle $ABCD$ ,$AB=10$ and $BC=15$. A point $P$ inside the rectangle such that $PB=12$ and $PC=9$.What is the length of $PA$ ?

I've calculated that $PA=10$ by using  the law of cosines applied to $\Delta BPA$.
However this is not the solution the author  intended as the book where this exercise comes from doesn't teach law of cosines but only basic trig relationships and  the really basics of geometry.

Thus what is the easy solution I haven't found ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(0,10),B(0,0),C(15,0),P(p,q)$ where $0\lt q$.

Then, solving
$$p^2+q^2=12^2\quad \text{and}\quad (p-15)^2+q^2=9^2$$
gives
$$p=\frac{48}{5},\quad q=\frac{36}{5}.$$

So, 
$$PA=\sqrt{\left(\frac{48}{5}\right)^2+\left(10-\frac{36}{5}\right)^2}=10.$$

Comment: Nice solution !Thanks ! Can you think of any other approach using synthetic methods ?Just for curiosity